# show / hide image based on amount of days javascript

Tags: javascript, image, getdate

I am trying to hide and show images within my div grid using javascript. I want the images to appear if the day is less than 15 and hide if it is greater than 15. I want a new image to appear each day and keep the previous days images too till it hits 15.

Can anyone help, I am very new to javascript and trying to write it from scratch!

```
<div class="grid-container">
                
  <div class="item"><div class="number">1.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image" src="img/01.jpeg"></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="number">2.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image" src="img/10.jpg"></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="number">3.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image" src="img/10.jpg"></div>  
  <div class="item"><div class="number">4.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image" src="img/10.jpg"></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="number">5.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image" src="img/10.jpg"></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="number">6.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image" src="img/10.jpg"></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="number">7.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image" src="img/10.jpg"></div>

    <div class="item"><div class="number">8.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image" src="img/10.jpg"></div>  
    <div class="item"><div class="number">9.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image" src="img/10.jpg"></div>  
    <div class="item"><div class="number">10.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image" src="img/10.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="number">11.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image" src="img/10.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="number">12.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image"></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="number">13.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image"></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="number">14.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image"></div>
                
    <div class="item"><div class="number">15.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image"></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="number">16.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image"></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="number">17.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image"></div>  
    <div class="item"><div class="number">18.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image"></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="number">19.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image"></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="number">20.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image"></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="number">21.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image"></div>
    
    <div class="item"><div class="number">22.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image"></div>  
    <div class="item"><div class="number">23.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image"></div>  
    <div class="item"><div class="number">24.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image"></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="number">25.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image"></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="number">26.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image"></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="number">27.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image"></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="number">28.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image"></div>
                
    <div class="item"><div class="number">29.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image"></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="number">30.</div><img class="calendar-img" id="image"></div>
                
</div>
</div>
   </div> 

<!-- end container -->
    

<script>

     var today_date = new Date().getDate();
    var 
    
    function image() {
    if(today_date = 15){
          document.getElementById("image").style.display = "none";
    }   
    else{ document.getElementById("image").style.display = "block"
    }
}

            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function image() {
    const images = document.querySelectorAll('#image')
    if(today_date = 15){
          images.forEach(e=>e.style.display='none')
    }   
    else{ 
         images.forEach(e=>e.style.display='block')
    }
}
```

You need to do this by **querySelectorAll**. It extract all matching elements and then we can hide/show by looping through the elements.